Find area of patch if two vector files overlap
I have two vector files containing polygons. I want to calculate the area of polygons in add if they are touched by polygons in re. I have tried but I only find the area of the intersected area, but I want the area calculated for the whole area and not only the intersection.
I started with raster files and turned them into shapefiles.
library(terra)

re= vrt("D:/relative.tif")
add = vrt("D:/additive.tif")

add.patch = patches(add)
re.patch = patches(re)
re.buff = buffer(re, 30)
re.buff[re.buff == 0] = NA

add.poly = as.polygons(add.patch)
re.poly = as.polygons(re.buff)

Then it goes wrong here:
# Intersect the polygon layers
intersected <- intersect(add.poly, re.poly)

# Calculate the area of the intersected polygons
intersected_area <- expanse(intersected)

I want it to something like:
if re intersects with add then calculate area of add
Here is the test data:
relative
additive

Your data is not available anymore.
